Why does hot air rise? Gravity based on density so electrons in higher shell further from nucleus have less gravitational force?
Are atoms with electrons in a higher state of energy, further away from the nucleus, effected less by gravity?  What does electron distance from nucleus have to do with the force of gravity or higher energy state have to do with gravity?  Is it because the electron is further away from nucleus and therefore creates less gravity itself in relation to all of the other atoms next to it?  What is the reason that liquids separate based on density during specific gravity tests?  Being spun with centrifugal force while held in a vial forces the liquid to stack up based on density when it is being accelerated in a direction like gravity is a force of acceleration towards earth.  So higher density molecules stack up from highest density at the furthest and less density inward.  Meaning that higher density stuff will be closer to the point of greatest acceleration than less density stuff.  Why?

Gravity has little to do with electron orbitals, it's way too weak compared to the electromagnetic force even if it's less for electrons further away.

There are 7 question marks, in your question, I will try to a cohesive anwer to everything.
Why hot air raises and why liquids stack in the vial?
As you correctly say, it comes down to density. Consider a container divided vertically in half and filled of water and oil (one per section). At some point we decide to open the door that separates the two liquids. They will both be affected by gravity and dragged down. But oil is less dense than water so to go towards the bottom of the container, it would have to move the wather somewhere. Whater has to do the same thing but this time is easy to lift the oil above it since it is less dense.
The same happens in the vial but here the force pulling "down" is not gravity but the centrifugal force given by the rotation of the vial.
Why is hot hair less dense?
Temperature is jus a measure of kinetc energy of atoms or molecules. Picture them as balls inside a box. The faster they move, the stronger and more frequently they will hit the side of the box. Now imagine the same thing bun inside a balloon, what you observe is that this higner number of impacts makes the balloon expand.
These are some cool videos about what happens when you freeze balloons with liquid nitrogen (it makes everything more dramatic but the principel is the same) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdMtGyNEEv8.
Does density has anything to do with electrons distance from the nuclueus?
You are correct in saying that excited electrons tends to be further away from the nucleus, but when millions and millions of molecules are togeter (like in a drop of water or a balloon of air) this does not affect so much the distance between atoms and molecules. The most part of a mass of an atom is in its nucleus, so the biggest factor that determines the density of something, at a macroscopic level, is the distance between nucluses, regardless of what electrons do. That's why the effect produced by temperature (or kinetic energy) on density was discovered and studied well before knowing that atoms were made of a nucleus and electrons at all.

Imagine you are in a dance hall. A large number of people are very tightly packed into lineups to get a drink at the bar. Even though each person is only a very small distance from the next person, they are bump into each other gently. A little further away a smaller number of people are slow dancing in a waltz step, positioned quite close together but still comfortable in bumping into each other. Still further away an even smaller number are dancing the jitterbug and wildly flailing their arms and legs about. Once again they have each gained the space they need to dance with only minor bumping into each other. The answer to your question simply comes down to how much space each person has to perform their activity. Obviously you could not dance the jitterbug in the lineup to the bar or you would get bounced into an area with fewer people. So you have to move further and further away the more you want to flail about until you reach the point of equilibrium.
It's the same on the Earth with hot air. Hot air that is vibrating rapidly obviously cannot move down through the Earth. So it must seek more and more space to perform it's dance. The only place that space is available is up! There is unlimited space the further up it goes. So it just keeps going up and up until it finds a region of equilibrium.  Each molecule of air, whether hot or cold, moves to the place of equilibrium where it can vibrate according to its temperature.
